# Is the Heighest weight vector in the Spinor rep of $SO(1,d-1)$ zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry, spinors, clifford-algebra

Consider the highest weight vector of the Spinor rep of $SO(1,d-1)$ where $d=2m+1$. It can be shown that:
$$\gamma_i \gamma_{m+i}v=v\tag{*}$$
I cannot see why this relation does not imply that $v=0$? My reasoning why it should be zero is as follows:

> Multiply both sides of * by $\gamma_{m+i} \gamma_i$ and use that (for $i\ne $1):
>   $$\gamma_i \gamma_i=I$$
>   then we get: $$v=\gamma_{m+i} \gamma_{i}v$$ using the fact that $\gamma_{m+i}$ and $\gamma_i$ anti-commute gives us:
>   $$v=-\gamma_i \gamma_{m+i}v$$
>   now sub in *:
>   $$v=-v$$
>   hence $$v=0$$

Can someone explain why this is wrong?

Comment: Please prove (\*), in particular, check all sign conventions. I suspect the correct relation in your case should be $\mathrm{i}\gamma_i\gamma_{m+i} v = v$, but this question is unanswerable without knowing how you got to (\*).

Comment: Frankly, I'm not gonna read through a bunch of handwritten notes to find some sign/factor of $\mathrm{i}$ that either you or the author of these notes dropped, and I don't think it is reasonable to expect any other user of this site to do so.

Comment: @ACuriousMind In all fairness this is never what I asked anyone to do, and didn't know it was down to a factor of $i$ error until your comment. Any answer explaining why $\mathrm{i}\gamma_i\gamma_{m+i} v = v$ is correct would do. (p.s. they are not my notes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operators $H_i = \gamma_i \gamma_{m+i}$ fulfill
$$ H_i^2 = - \eta_{ii}\eta_{(m+i)(m+i)},$$
and therefore for $i$ not time-like we have $H_i^2 = -1$. This means that $H_i$ has eigenvalues of $\pm\mathrm{i}$ (just observe that $H_i$ is diagonalizable and the eigenvalues must square to $-1$), so your equation (*) cannot be correct when $i$ is not time-like, which I presume is what you mean by $i\neq 1$, and should instead be
$$ \gamma_i \gamma_{m+i} v = \mathrm{i}v,$$
which leads to no contradiction.